# Parse text file of multiple different SQL statements into array of each statement

Tags: sql, regex, parsing

I have SQL statements in a text file. I want to have an array of each statement.

Something like that:

```
sqlScript.split(/;[ ]*?\n*/).filter((stmt) => !isEmptyScript(stmt));
```

But this only efficient with simple statements without declare or begin.

This is example of the statements (you can see here 3 different statements):

```
CREATE TABLE USERS 
(
    username VARCHAR(256),
    password VARCHAR(256),
    last_update_time TIMESTAMP
);

BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name            =>  'AUDIT_RETENTION_POLICY',
   job_type            =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action          =>  'DECLARE dateForRemove date :=TRUNC(SYSDATE- 30 + 1);
                            BEGIN
                              DELETE FROM AUDIT WHERE AUDIT_ID IN (SELECT TRAIL_ID
                                FROM TRAIL WHERE CREATED_AT < dateForRemove);
                              DELETE FROM TRAIL WHERE CREATED_AT < dateForRemove;
                            END;',
   start_date          =>  trunc(sysdate),
   repeat_interval     =>  'FREQ=DAILY',
   enabled            => true
  );
END;


DECLARE
  CONFIG_ID     CONSTANT NUMBER   := 0;
  TYPE       CONSTANT NUMBER   := 5;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO DIFF_TYPES(type_id, type_name) VALUES (TYPE,'myType');

  INSERT ALL
      INTO TABLE2 (ID, DIFF_TYPE, NAME) VALUES (CONFIG_ID, TYPE, 'test')
      INTO TABLE2 (ID, DIFF_TYPE, NAME) VALUES (CONFIG_ID, TYPE, 'test2')
      INTO TABLE2 (ID, DIFF_TYPE, NAME) VALUES (CONFIG_ID, TYPE, 'test3')
  SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
END;
```

Comment: try spliting the file at all newlines or double newlines. In your example you have the statements seperated by empty lines. Split at them...